# Issue with creating and looping through json object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to create a json object in js, use ajax to send it to a php page and loop through it in the php page.

My code is as follows

form page

```
<html>
    <body>
    Input 1: <input type="text" data-id="1" data-old="30"/><br>
    Input 2:<input type="text" data-id="2" data-old="40"/><br>
    Input 3:<input type="text" data-id="3" data-old="50"/><br>

    <input type="text" id="max" value="3" hidden/>

    <button type="button" id="proceed">Go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

js

```
$("#proceed").on("click",function(){
var num=$("#max").val();
var array=[];  //[] or {} ??
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    var old=$('input[data-id="'+i+'"]').data("old");
    var new=$('input[data-id="'+i+'"]').val();
    var deduct;
    if(new!==old && new!==""){
        deduct=old-new;
        array.push({"pid":i,"deduct":deduct});
    }

    var updateArray = JSON.stringify(array);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../control/stock-c.php",
        data:{updateArray:updateArray, func:"manualSync"},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(){
            alert("yay");
        }        
    });

}
});
```

stock-c.php

```
require_once '../model/stock-m.php';
$updateArray=$_POST["updateArray"];
$array=  json_decode($updateArray);
$obj=new Stock();
foreach($array as $obj1){
    $result=$obj->deductMainstock($obj1->pid,$obj1->deduct);
}
return $result;
```

The Stock class exists in the the stock-m.php and I can confirm that the method deductMainstock() works (includes a mysqli update query).

However when running my code it seems that the deductMainStock() hasn't worked. I know there's a bulk of code so to keep it simple I need to know the following:

1. Is the var array created in js file done properly?? I need to create a json object to send the details using ajax in the following format:

array=[{"pid"=1,"deduct"=a_value},{"pid"=2,"deduct"=another_value},{"pid"=3,"deduct"=another_value}]

2. Is the ajax call in js file correct? I used JSON.stringify() to convert the above array into json for sending over ajax.
3. Am I looping through the array properly in stock-c.php? I need to send "pid" and "deduct" as number variables to the deductMainstock() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please change the variable name `var new` to something else since its reserved keyword.
2. `var updateArray = JSON.stringify(array);` You no need to stringify the array.
3. Move the ajax call out side the `for` loop.

Below is the updated code

**Script**

```
<script>
$("#proceed").on("click",function(){
  var num=$("#max").val();
  var array=[];  //[] or {} ??
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
      var old=$('input[data-id="'+i+'"]').data("old");
      var new_val=$('input[data-id="'+i+'"]').val();
      var deduct;
      if(new_val!==old && new_val!==""){
          deduct=old-new_val;
          array.push({"pid":i,"deduct":deduct});
      }

  }
  if(array.length){
     $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"../control/stock-c.php",
       data:{updateArray:array, func:"manualSync"},
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(){
         alert("yay");
       }        
     });
  }

});
</script>
```

**PHP**

Post value will be array so remove the `json_decode` from your code.

```
<?php 
require_once '../model/stock-m.php';
$array = $_POST["updateArray"];
$obj = new Stock();
foreach ($array as $obj1) {
    $result = $obj->deductMainstock($obj1->pid,$obj1->deduct);
}
return $result;

?>
```

Hope this will help.